vscode haskell extension error message "openTempFile: invalid argument (Invalid argument)compiler"
I am new to Haskell and when I code Haskell on vscode, an error message says "openTempFile: invalid argument (Invalid argument)compiler". Even though there is no syntax error and I can load the file into ghci and run the functions, it's annoying and I was trying to figure out how to remove that message.
The image of error message is attached

The original code is here, file name is type_inference.hs:
-- Type inference

split xs = (as, bs)
    where as = take n xs
          bs = drop n xs
          n  = div (length xs) 2

partition (piv:xs) = (los, his)
    where los = filter (<piv)  xs
          his = filter (>=piv) xs

This is the Haskell extension that I'm using:

I download Haskell using ghcup:

I tried to reinstall haskell and extension but doesn't work
I notice that the error message occurs when the file name is long (Files with openTempFile error highlighted in red)

I'm using Windows 11 23h2.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Please [edit] your question to convert images into text, and use a [code block] for any code you have. Readers can then search the text or run the code to reproduce your issue.
